# A criterion for abelian $C^*$ algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$ algebra such that for any two positive elements $x$, $y$ in $A$, whenever $x\leq y$ we have that $x^2\leq y^2$. Prove that $A$ is abelian.

Comment: Is this homework?  I don't know the solution off the top of my head, but problems phrased in the imperative often are.

Comment: This is not a homework. I am reading Jesse Petersen's notes on von Neumann algebras. I have done other exercises. But I could not solve this one.

Comment: Right; usually exercises from a book are better received if you (1) indicate that they *are* exercises and (2) say what you've tried.

Comment: See Proposition 1.3.9 of "C*-Algebras and Their Automorphism Groups" (second edition) by G. K. Pedersen. It takes a little work.